# Why can't I see a virtual directory created in Visual Studio 2013 for Local IIS in IIS Manager?

Tags: iis, visual-studio-2013, webserver, iis-8.5

I'm trying to debug a problem where my local IIS has mysteriously decided to not recognize my virtual directory.

In my MVC 4 project, my web server is set to "Local IIS" and my project URL is set to `http://localhost/MySite`.  When I hit the `Create Virtual Directory` button, I get the message "The virtual directory was created successfully."

But when I go IIS Manager and click on `Default Web Site | MySite | View virtual directories` no virtual directories are listed.  This is also the case for the web site where the virtual directory does work.

Why can't I see a virtual directory created in `Visual Studio 2013` for Local IIS in `IIS Manager`?

Where can I see the virtual directories created by VS?

Comment: You sure it's getting created on full fat IIS and not IIS Express?

Comment: Server is set to Local IIS so if the "Create Virtual Directory" button was creating the VD in IIS Express or Cassini that would be...strange.

Comment: Did you manage to solve this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try one of the following:

1. Check the checkbox override application root URL below create virtual directory option and then click on create virtual directory again.

Or:

2. Right click on Explore to default web site. Inside the opened windows explorer create a folder with the name same as used in your project URL (just after localhost) in VS 2013. Example - create applications folder for url `http://localhost/applications/test`. Refresh IIS and it should work.